# Google Sheets - Conditioning Formatting for Date Expiry

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, conditional-formatting

I have a spreadsheet with different dates for different clients where the contract expiry date turns red when it's due to expire in 60 days or overdue. The formula I am using is:

```
=AND((X:X>0), (X:X<60))
```

But it seems it's not looking at the year, so for example I have a date of 01/09/2021 which is red as the date has already passed (01/09), but it's showing red when it shouldn't because its 2021.

Any ideas? :) Thanks!!

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: Do you have any other formatting/using any other formulae for the cells you are applying the conditional formatting on? @Beth

Comment: @ale13 - Literally just the one above :(

Comment: @player0 - I have added you onto my spreadsheet to edit - really appreciate it thank you!

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=(X:X>=1)*(X:X<=TODAY()+60)
```

[image]

Comment: That didn't work for some reason, certain dates are fine and then some are red for 2021, for example 11/05/2021 is fine but 01/1/2021 is showing red.

Comment: My spreadsheet is work related so it only lets me share the link with my company but if you'd give me an email to share it with that'll work - thank you very much.

Comment: @Beth I checked your sheet & I believe `1/jan/2021` should be red because today's `10/nov/2020+60days` equals `9/jan/2021` so `1/jan/2021` is still within that 60-day range. Also please note that you got there non-existing dates like `31/6/2020`